# django 2.0 file(view) changes does not effect in frontend

Tags: python, django

In my django 2.0 application, when I change something in view, it does not effect in frontend even closing the server by ctrl+c or ctrl+z. I am using windows. It works when I manually close python process from task manager. It's not good process to code and restarting server each time in development. If I have a simple HttpResponse of string like return HttpResponse('test') and changes the string(test) to any thing, it does not show the updated string, instead it shows test.

How to overcome this, any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you running the server with the manage.py runserver command?

Comment: yes, python manage.py runserver @at14

Comment: Strange, hot/auto reload should work with manage.py runserver